# ArcMap: export each x/y coordinates to a separate row

Tags: arcpy, export

I am trying to sort out how the coordinates of each point in a multipoint or polyline feature could be exported to a .txt with python so the exported file looks like this:

```
point1_coordinates_x
point1_coordinates_y
point2_coordinates_x
point2_coordinates_y
.
.
.
pointn_coordinates_x
pointn_coordinates_y
```

I don't need the elevation / z value in further processing of the data, only x & y coordinates. Is there any way to easily generate this output with python?

I know of the export to csv / txt settings in ArcGIS, also of the standard python code matching that function - however I struggle with putting each value in a separate row.

Comment: are you looking for some help with coding the script? if so, please add a snippet of your code so we can see what you've done so far.

Comment: [This page](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/python/reading-geometries.htm) shows examples on reading geometries, if you know how to create and edit a text file you're done.

Comment: If you just explode the features (multipart to single part) and add xy fields you can achieve this without any scripting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This arcpy example will loop through features and coordinates to output to screen.  Could be modified to suit your output requirements.

```
import arcpy, os

workspace = r'N:\GISSE\PtCoords'
arcpy.env.workspace = os.path.join(workspace, r'test.gdb') # Location of feature class
inputFeatureClass = r'mymultipoint' # Name of feature class to inspect

fields = ['OID@', 'SHAPE@X', 'SHAPE@Y'] # OID and coordinate info to get from feature
oidSet = set() # To record each OID as it's processed

vertexArray =  arcpy.da.FeatureClassToNumPyArray(inputFeatureClass, fields, explode_to_points=True)

for oid, shapeX, shapeY in vertexArray:
    # Identify each vertex from feature
    if not oid in oidSet: # if the OID is new, then reset vertex count
        i = 1
        oidSet.add(oid)
    else: # Otherwise increase counter for next vertex
        i += 1 
    # Output OID, Vertex Number, and X or Y Coordinate
    print "OID = {}, Vertex = {}, X = {}".format(oid, i, shapeX)
    print "OID = {}, Vertex = {}, Y = {}".format(oid, i, shapeY)
```

This will output something like:

```
OID = 1, Vertex = 1, X = 1878550.1884
OID = 1, Vertex = 1, Y = 5819949.3209
OID = 1, Vertex = 2, X = 1879165.1529
OID = 1, Vertex = 2, Y = 5822540.957
OID = 2, Vertex = 1, X = 1883206.3482
OID = 2, Vertex = 1, Y = 5819707.7277
OID = 2, Vertex = 2, X = 1884524.1292
OID = 2, Vertex = 2, Y = 5818609.5768
```

All you'd need to do is modify the `print` statements to the output format you require, and send to a text file if the print isn't enough.

---

As per comment about running on shapefiles rather than geodatabase, just make some changes to the workspace lines at the start of the code:

```
workspace = r'N:\GISSE\PtCoords'
arcpy.env.workspace = workspace # Location of shapefile
inputFeatureClass = r'mymultipoint.shp' # Name of shapefile to inspect
```

Comment: Thanks! This solution works like a charm and I was able to modify it to my needs. One question though: is it possible to alter the script so it also works with normal .shps not included in a GDB?

Comment: @TheMiningArchaeologist I have added an extra snippet of code that should run on shapefiles